# Good way to combine two List<T>s in .NET 2.0?

Tags: .net-2.0, list, union

I have two lists I need to form the union of, but I'm in .NET 2.0 so the Union() method appears to be out.  These are lists of integers, so no problem with the equality comparisons.  What's a good way to go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about (using Dictionary keys as a hashtable):

```
public static List<T> Union<T>(List<T> first, List<T> second) {
    List<T> newList = new List<T>(first.Count + second.Count);
    Dictionary<T, object> firstItems = new Dictionary<T, object>(first.Count);

    foreach (T item in first) {
        newList.Add(item);
        firstItems.Add(item, null); 
    }

    foreach (T item in second) {
        if (!firstItems.ContainsKey(item)) {
            newList.Add(item);
        }
    }

    return newList;
}
```

This will maintain the item order in `first` and `second`, while still using an O(1) check for duplicate items between the lists

Comment: Just note this wont remove dups in first

Answer (score 3):

You could just add them together and remove the duplicates:

```
  public List<T> Union<T>(List<T> firstList, List<T> secondList)
  {
     Dictionary<T, int> tmp = new Dictionary<T, int>();

     foreach (T val in firstList)
     {
        tmp[val] = 1;
     }

     foreach (T val in secondList)
     {
        tmp[val] = 1;
     }

     return new List<T>(tmp.Keys);
  }
```

Comment: Using a dictionary may change the order of the elements in the list.

Comment: And will alter firstList as a side-effect of the operation

Comment: @CodeSavvyGeek Union of two sets by definition is associative and commutative, order doesn't matter.

Comment: There's no need for combined_list - you can just stick firstList and secondList straight into the dictionary

Answer (score 1):

How about a simple foreach, only adding elements that aren't already in the list:

```
foreach (int item in list2)
{
    if (!list1.Contains(item))
    {
        list1.Add(item);
    }
}
```

This will preserve the order of the lists.

Comment: Contains could be slow if the lists are large.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [linqbridge](http://code.google.com/p/linqbridge/) to let you use LINQ to Objects while still targeting Framework 2.0, if you have Visual Studio 2008.

And push, push, push to move to .NET 3.5. LINQ and lambdas change the way you think about code (for the better, IMHO).

Comment: We can't use .NET 3.5 yet on our packaged software, as some people may not have installed it yet (think XP machines run by a BOFH)